# The imported library 'package:geolocator/model/position.dart' can't have a part-of directive

Tags: dart, flutter, cross-platform, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

In my flutter app I have been using these following plugin [permission_handler](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission_handler), [geolocator](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocator) and [google_api_availibility](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_api_availability).
I could have added this plugin from flutter package **from pubspec.yml**, however, in my app i am using [google_map_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter#-readme-tab-) plugin which has been using AndroidX support libraries. Due this reason I have added those library locally with some changes to work with AndroidX. So my app structure and pubspecs looks like this.
[image]

So in my app pubspecs.yml

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
permission_handler:
  path: my_permission_handler
geolocator:
  path: flutter-geolocator
```

My my_permission_handler's pubspecs.yml

```
flutter:
 plugin:
   androidPackage: com.baseflow.permissionhandler
   pluginClass: PermissionHandlerPlugin
```

My api_availibility's pubspec.yml

```
flutter:
  plugin:
    androidPackage: com.baseflow.googleapiavailability
    pluginClass: GoogleApiAvailabilityPlugin
```

My geolocator's pubspec.yml

```
dependencies:
  meta: "^1.0.5"
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  permission_handler:
    path: ../my_permission_handler
  google_api_availability:
    path: ../flutter-google-api-availability
```

Now when in one of the project's classes I tried to import a model class from geolocator like this
[image]

but it shows this error **The imported library 'package:geolocator/model/position.dart' can't have a part-of directive**

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, please help me.

Comment: This should be reported as bug. Code that is not supposed to be imported by users of the package should be in `lib/src/**`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of let's look into the code for **package:geolocator/modles/position.dart**

It says `part of geolocator;` at the very beginning of the file meaning this class is a part of the plugin which is exposed in the file **package:geolocator/** like this `part 'models/position.dart';`. So here in your client code you don't need to import the class Position this way.

if you modify your import statement this way the error will be gone

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
```

I hope it helps.